# Extract a value from a single line of JSON

Tags: json, awk, sed, grep

How can extract the value using a sed or awk command where jp or any JSON content in not allowed?

```
{"test":{"components":[{"metric":"complexity","value":"90"}]}}

Output:

 90
```

I tried with the below command, but I am getting the below error:

```
def value=sh (script: 'grep -Po \'(?<="value":")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*\'  sample.txt')
```

But getting the below error from the [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) script:

> grep: missing terminating ] for character class

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem(not my downvote btw).

Comment: Yes I have used a command and it is working grep -Po '(?<="value":")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*'  sample.txt but in jenkins I am trying to copy to a variable but it is throwing an error. 
grep: missing terminating ] for character class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though passing JSON content should be done by a JSON parser, since the OP told the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool is not allowed to adding to this solution here, strictly written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk 'match($0, /"value":"[0-9]+/){print substr($0, RSTART+9,  RLENGTH-9)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: I am adding this to a def variable but it is null
 def value=sh (script: 'awk \'match($0,/"value":"[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)}\'  value.txt')
but It is working seperately.Is there anyway to resolve it

Comment: @user3428736, you mean  you are calling this in python script?

Comment: I am using it within pipeline scripts using groovy. I need to assign it to a variable to use it.